# Any funny *nix one-liners?

Tags: untagged

> This question is left open because it was historically allowed, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site and would be closed if asked today.
>
> More info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq

I saw a t-shirt reading 'anything you say gets piped to /dev/null', not incredibly funny but amusing at least.

Does anyone else have any good one-liner *nix jokes?

Comment: these are amusing :) i love the way us geeks have the rather awesome sense of humour! fsk the win!

Answer (score 38):

- `I mount my soul at /dev/null` - a colleague
- [image]

Comment: AAALT... TEXXXT!

Comment: I would have the dialog as this: Make me a sandwich - What? Make it yourself. - sudo!! -Okay

Answer (score 30):

> Unix is user-friendly. It's just picky about who its friends are.

(I don't know the origin. There are several variant formulations floating around. [T-shirt (first google hit)](http://antcom.spreadshirt.de/unix-is-user-friendly-A3864238)

Answer (score 29):

> There are two major products of Berkeley, CA -- LSD and UNIX.  We don't 
>   believe this to be strictly by coincidence.

— [Jeremy S. Anderson](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.conspiracy/browse_thread/thread/7f5b9252211b6801/73ecb360a8247f19#73ecb360a8247f19)

Comment: I went back and found the original of this quote on Usenet & it is actually as I've edited it.

Comment: LSD was synthesized by a Swiss scientist. I would not define it a Berkley product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSD)

Comment: Surely that would be better are "Two things came out fo Berkeley: LSD and BSD. Coincidence?"...

Answer (score 26):

> Those who do not understand UNIX are condemned to reinvent it, poorly.

— Henry Spencer

Comment: Henry is an amazingly knowledgeable guy about space stuff too!  Very eclectic fellow!

Comment: By a coincidence, Henry Spencer is also the name of the lead character in the 1977 film "Eraserhead", so googling for this name gives lots of images of someone with electric-shock style hair.

Comment: That is actually more sad than amusing since it documents a very real phenomenon.

Answer (score 24):

UNIX was not designed to stop you from doing stupid things, because that would also stop you from doing clever things.

*— Doug Gwyn*

Answer (score 21):

FreeBSD make:

```
$ make love
Not war.
$
```

or `bsdmake` on OS X:

```
$ make love
make: don't know how to make love. Stop
$
```

Answer (score 21):

These are all taken from [here](http://www.sanitarium.net/jokes/getjoke.cgi?71). A lot of these don't seem to work on newer shells, but they're still possible to laugh at.

```
 % make fire
 Make: Don't know how to make fire. Stop. 

 % why not?
 No match. 

 % gotta light?
 No match. 

 % !1984
 1984: Event not found. # (on some systems) 

 % How's my lovemaking?
 Unmatched '. 

 % "How would you rate Bush's incompetence? 
 Unmatched ". 

 % [Where is Jimmy Hoffa?
 Missing ]. 

 % [Where is my brain?
 Missing ]. 

 % ^How did the sex change^ operation go? 
 Modifier failed. 

 % If I had a ( for every $ Congress spent, what would I have? 
 Too many ('s. 

 % man: why did you get a divorce?
 man:: Too many arguments. 

 % %blow
 %blow: No such job. 

 % \(-
 (-: Command not found. 

 % sh
 $ PATH=pretending! /usr/ucb/which sense 
 no sense in pretending!
 $ mkdir matter; cat >matter
 matter: cannot create 

 % cd /tmp
 % touch this; chmod 000 this
 % ln -s /usr/bin/touch U
 % U this
 U: cannot touch this: no write permission 

 % rm meese-ethics
 rm: meese-ethics nonexistent 

 % ar m God
 ar: God does not exist 

 % make love
 Make: Don't know how to make love. Stop. 

 Supposedly on older Sun's make will also tell you

 Make: Don't know how to make love. How about war instead?

 % sleep with me
 bad character 

 % ^What is saccharine?
 Bad substitute. 

 % drink yellow_pages
 yellow_pages: Is a directory 

 %touch me
 %chmod 000 me
 %touch me
 touch: cannot touch me: permission denied 

 % ar x "my love life"
 ar: my love life does not exist 

 % ar x "matey, the treasure"
 ar: matey, the treasure does not exist 

 % talk Gorvachev@Kremlin
 talk: Kremlin: Can't figure out network address. 

 % talk Comrade Khruchev
 [Your party is not logged on]
```

Comment: Haha: '$ ar m God
ar: creating God` (GNU ar (GNU Binutils) 2.20.1.20100303)

Answer (score 20):

I didn't see this for a while now:

> Unix is sexy: who | grep -i blonde |
>   date; cd ~; unzip; touch; strip;
>   finger; mount; gasp; yes; uptime;
>   umount; sleep

Comment: gasp? what's gasp?

Comment: gasp is an assembly preprocessor (Gnu ASsembly pre Processor)

Answer (score 20):

If you have any trouble sounding condescending, find a UNIX user to show you how it's done.

*— Scott Adams, Dilbert Cartoonist*

Comment: i love this one

Answer (score 15):

Here are a couple of T-shirt slogans:

There is no place like ~

My favorite:
Thou shalt not kill -9

Comment: `There is no place like ~` is so much better than [`There is no place like 127.0.0.1`](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/generic/5d6a/) which makes no sense...

Answer (score 14):

From Linus Torvalds : "Software is like sex: it's better when it's free".

Answer (score 14):

> Here's a nickel, kid. Get yourself a better computer.

That line, from an old Dilbert cartoon, is now [famous enough](http://tomayko.com/writings/that-dilbert-cartoon) that you don't even need the rest of the cartoon anymore.

Here it is anyway:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

OK, this is cheating, but still a lot of fun!

Play around with the command line version of [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/) webcomic: 
**http://uni.xkcd.com/**

Go ahead, type in your commands!

Here's what you you can expect:

[image]

Comment: $ ed

You are not a diety.

Comment: Fun fact. It lets you sudo rm -rf /. Also "locate raptor" and "locate keys" get interestng results.

Answer (score 9):

```
apt-get install wife :P
```

http://en.tiraecol.net/modules/comic/comic.php?content_id=161
[image]

http://www.tiraecol.net/modules/comic/comic.php?content_id=162
[image]

Answer (score 8):

> You don't exist. Go away.

Message from various programs when they try to look up your user info by user ID and that fails.

Reasons that can happen:

- `/etc/passwd` is corrupt
- the user got deleted between the program getting its doomed ID and attempting the lookup
- various weirdnesses involving [the `utmp` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp)

Answer (score 8):

Found in early Unix sources:

```
/*
 * You are not expected to understand this.
 */
if(rp->p_flag & SSWAP) {
    rp->p_flag =& ~SSWAP;
    aretu(u.u_ssav);
}
```

(Lightly edited.)

Comment: Note the now-obsolete =& instead of &=

Answer (score 8):

```
stop@hammertime:~> touch /this
touch: cannot touch "/this": Permission denied
```

Answer (score 7):

Seen on a t-shirt a while back:

```
rm -rf /bin/laden
```

Answer (score 7):

My favorites:

```
UNIX is basically a simple operating system, but you have to be a genius to 
understand the simplicity.
    Dennis Ritchie
```

And:

```
One of my most productive days was throwing away 1000 lines of code.
    Ken Thomson
```

Answer (score 6):

From http://q4td.blogspot.com/

“Unix never says ‘please’”
    — Rob Pike

Answer (score 6):

```
Sex Drugs and UNIX (Usenix '83)
```

From the cover of the book 'A quarter Century of Unix' by Peter H. Salus

Answer (score 6):

when installed :

[fortune](http://linux.die.net/man/6/fortune)

Comment: I really don't get this one

Comment: You mean "fortune -o" to get the offensive ones :)

Comment: Fortune is a program that prints from a database of oneliners (fsvo line).

Comment: oh snap... nice answer +1

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft is not the answer. Microsoft is the question. NO (or Linux) is the answer.

- taken from [here](http://www.linuxweb.com/lw_quotes.html)

  $ man woman
  No manual entry for woman

Comment: If Windows is the answer, it must have been a very silly question.

Comment: well... Microsoft is the answer on many occasions... like 'who is to blame?'

Answer (score 4):

```
joe@joebox:~$ whatis linux
```

Answer (score 4):

**The Sad Story**

```
[root@localhost root]# gcc homework.c -o homework.c
[root@localhost root]#
[root@localhost root]# ls
homework.c
[root@localhost root]#
```

**The Contradiction**

> *less > more*
>
> The name came from the joke of doing
>   "backwards more." To help remember the
>   difference between less and more, a
>   common joke is to say, "less > more,"
>   implying that less has greater
>   functionality than more. - from wikipedia

Comment: this is awesome

Answer (score 3):

> I read your mail.

Comment: It'd be much better with `I read /var/spool/mail/$USER` (or is it referring to the command? Hmm...)

Comment: @new123456, It is a pun because the sentence is semantically ambiguous. A BOFH knows that lusers think 'ah nice guy, he is reading my mail I send him - how thoughtful!' - and at the same time he is recognized by fellow BOFHs as one of them (BOFHs don't care about the privacy of correspondence because they are BOFHs - they read the all the mail of their lusers if they are bored).

Answer (score 3):

A more traditional version of the dirty joke echox posted:

TOUCH GREP UNZIP MOUNT FSCK FSCK FSCK UMOUNT

Answer (score 3):

hm, maybe this one:

> In a world without walls or fences who needs windows or gates.

I know it's lame but true too :)

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to *nix but related to coders:

> Code is like fart, you support only yours.

Answer (score 0):

[root@satish:~/Desktop]$ whatis linux

linux: nothing appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

> Linux is like a wigwam. No windows, no gates, apache inside!

Answer (score -3):

Linux comes from the community, Windows comes from a box.